# MathJax: How to change font in equation mode?

Tags: fonts, mathjax

MathML still effectively uses `Computer Modern` whenever you want to render an equation.

On a website, if I use MathJax `$\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i} D(i)$` gets converted into:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
  <munderover>
    <mo>&#x2211;<!-- ∑ --></mo>
    <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
      <mi>i</mi>
      <mo>=</mo>
      <mn>0</mn>
    </mrow>
    <mi>n</mi>
  </munderover>
  <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
    <mrow>
      <mo>(</mo>
      <mfrac linethickness="0">
        <mi>n</mi>
        <mi>i</mi>
      </mfrac>
      <mo>)</mo>
    </mrow>
  </mrow>
  <mi>D</mi>
  <mo stretchy="false">(</mo>
  <mi>i</mi>
  <mo stretchy="false">)</mo>
</math>
```

Are there ways to specify which font to render tokens like `<mi>` or `<mo>`.  Let's say I'd like to use [Kite One](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Kite+One) for the variables in my font, so as not to clash with the rest of my web site.

http://content.altfonts.com:81/img/K/I/Kite-Onea.png

[image]

Actually, the fonts look really nice.  But how could I change MathML if I needed to?

---

**EDIT** More generally, I seem to be asking if Cascading Style Sheets exist for MathML

- [Default CSS Style Sheet for MathML](http://www.w3.org/TR/mathml-for-css/#d2e2482)
- [CSS-compartible attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML2/chapter2.html#fund.cssatt)

I hope this is a question for **tex.stackexchange** it may be a question for StackOverflow at this point

Comment: Sorry, but this is off topic here: it has nothing to do with TeX.

Comment: @egreg what's a more appropriate place to put this? by all means migrate my question

Comment: It's off topic here, you should ask on S.O. (or better) the mathjax help forum see the links on the mathjax tag wiki http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/mathjax/info